# Setting Triggers for Custom Properties WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I have created a custom button that has a boolean flag on it to say whether it is selected or not.  If it is selected i want to change the background color of the button to allow the user to know what control they are looking at quickly.  The problem is that i can not get the trigger to work correctly.  Everything that i have seen on here, i have tried but i still get errors during the InitializeComponent section of my code.

Here are the properties that i am dealing with

```
Private mIsSelected As Boolean = False
Public Property IsSelected() As Boolean
    Get
        Return mIsSelected
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        mIsSelected = value
    End Set
End Property


Public Shared ReadOnly MyBackgroundProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyBackground",
                                                                                                GetType(LinearGradientBrush), GetType(RentAdjButtons),
                                                                                                    New PropertyMetadata(New LinearGradientBrush(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#3366CC"), ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#0000FF"), New System.Windows.Point(0.5, 0), New System.Windows.Point(0.5, 1))))


Private mMyBackground As New LinearGradientBrush
Public Property MyBackground() As LinearGradientBrush
    Get
        Return mMyBackground
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As LinearGradientBrush)
        mMyBackground = value
    End Set
End Property
```

and here is my XMAL

```
 <Style TargetType="Com:RentAdjButtons">
            <Setter Property="MyBackground" Value="{StaticResource DefaultBackground}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="MyBackground" Value="{StaticResource SelectedButton}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
```

Currently the error i am getting is "Property can not be null on Trigger"

Thank you in advance for any assistance

Comment: your IsSelected property should also be a DependencyProperty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ToggleButton which has this property by default.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of the Toggle button I ended up re-building the User control using that instead

Answer (score 0):

The `Trigger.Property` must be a `DependencyProperty` for the trigger to work. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.property.aspx) for the documentation. You'll need to change your class property `IsSelected` into a `DependencyProperty`.

Also, your getter/setter for MyBackground should be defined as documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3) using `SetValue` and `GetValue`:

```
    Public Property State() As Boolean
      Get
          Return CType(Me.GetValue(StateProperty), Boolean)
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
          Me.SetValue(StateProperty, value)
      End Set
    End Property
    Public Shared ReadOnly StateProperty As DependencyProperty = 
      DependencyProperty.Register("State", GetType(Boolean), GetType(MyStateControl),
      New PropertyMetadata(False))
```